# How can I print a list as a set?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
my_list = ["str1","str2","str3"]
```

I am trying show this like in a `dict.`

Like trying:

```
print (f"Categories: {mylist}")
```

Output -> `Categories: {'str1', 'str2', 'str3'}`

Comment: no matter if I have a dict or not, just trying to have the output that I wrote

Comment: my_list - you are using as mylist in print

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`set(my_list)` would make it. It's a set not a `dict`

```
my_list = ["str1","str2","str3"]


set(my_list)
{'str1', 'str2', 'str3'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by formatting the output so it comes out the way you want:

```
def format_as_set(list_):
    return ('{' + ', '.join(repr(element) for element in list_) + '}')

my_list = ["str1","str2","str3"]

print('Categories:', format_as_set(my_list))  # -> Categories: {'str1', 'str2', 'str3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you trying to do is to create a set actually. Format of dictionary is {key: value}. For set, you can do is:

```
my_set = set(my_list)
```